# Java cannot get any response from my servlet

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, servlets

My jsp page:

```
<button data-ng-click="login()">Fetch data from server</button>
```

mainController.js

```
    $scope.login = function() {
    var xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttpReq.open('POST', "http://localhost:8080/WEB-war/FES", false);
    xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    xmlHttpReq.send(JSON.stringify($scope.strings));
    if (xmlHttpReq.status === 200) {
        alert(xmlHttpReq.responseText)
    }

}
```

FileEditServlet.java

```
@WebServlet("/FileEditServlet")
public class FileEditServlet extends HttpServlet {

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("inside do POST");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("response");
    response.getWriter().write("do something omg");

 }
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"                      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FileEditServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.FileEditServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>FileEditServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/FES</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Once I press on the button Fetch data from server and call the login function the function in the mainContrller is called, and the output is empty. I mean the alert is empty like there is no response.

Also, there is nothing in the console, but 2 words: "test test"
which I simply cannot find in my code.

Comment: What is the value of `xmlHttpReq.status`?

Comment: 200, it comes to the line, and it sets off the alert...but its empty

Comment: You can see this line `inside do POST` in your console right?

Comment: Please try to add `response.getWriter().flush()`

Comment: in the console there is only: test test, and i have no idea where it comes from....also i added now the flush() stuff into the code, but nothing

Comment: Is there a better way to do the same procedure? that is get the comuication between the servlet and the angularjs controller?

Comment: I think the function per se is ok, without knowing any details of your application, it looks grand. A response status 200 means the web.xml settings also with no problem. This line `PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()` and `response.getWriter()` looks a smell to me as you tried to `getWriter` twice. Try to remove one of them.

Comment: I put it into an answer, might be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I will put this into an answer which I think might be clearer than appending the comments.

I think web.xml and js part shouldn't cause the problem. And return string `test test` definitely should be somewhere in your code, do a text search in your project (if you are using Eclipse).

The problem however, I guess is because you try to call `getWriter` method from `HttpServletResponse` twice - the first one does a `println` second one write into the stream. You could try to remove one of these. Here's a bit example:

```
@WebServlet("/FileEditServlet")
public class FileEditServlet extends HttpServlet {

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("inside do POST");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out .getWriter().write("do something omg");

 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Why your url is http://localhost:8080/WEB-war/FES ?

try to change to http://localhost:8080/FileEditServlet/FES

Comment: once i do that, the alert wont trigger at all

Comment: your configuration is little bit confusing. if you using @WebServlet annotation then web.xml is optional, but you define servlet again with another url pattern. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html

Comment: so u say, i can remove the servlet part from the web.xml? and then use that what u suggested above?